# How to run and update a program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, repeat

I’m having trouble getting my “money” variable to update after the player wins/loses money.
I’ve tried for loops, while loops, and functions but I’m stuck.

What I am trying to do is get the program to run with an initial amount of money equal to 100, and then update that amount of money to that of what the player has won /loss during the first round.

After that, I want the program to continuously run and update the money variable as the player continues to win/lose money.

Here is the code to express my idea.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the casino")
money = 100

def bet():
   money = money
   greeting = input("Would you like to bet? yes/no ")
   if greeting == ("yes"):
       pass
   elif greeting == ("no"):
       print("Then leave")
       exit()
   print("Total Money is: " + str(money))
   print("_____________________________________")
   player = input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors: ")
   bot = (random.randrange(1,4))
   rock = 1
   paper = 2
   scissors = 3

   if money <= 0:
       print("We don't let the poor bet")
       exit()
   else:
       pass
       #betting procedure
   print("You have " + str(money) + " shekels")
   print("How many shekels are you betting? ")
   bet = int(input("Max Bet: 100 "))

   if 0 < bet <= 100:
       bet_money = money - bet #total amount of money while betting
   elif bet <= 0:
       print("That's not how it works, you've been kicked from the casino")
       exit()
   else:
       print("That's not allowed, you've been kicked from the casino")
       exit()
       print("")

       #What Bot Picks,
   if (bot == 1):
       print("The computer chose rock")
   elif (bot == 2):
       print("The computer chose paper")
   elif (bot == 3):
       print("The computer chose scissors")

       #What Player Picks,
   if (player == "rock"):
       print("You chose rock")
   elif (player == "scissors"):
       print("You chose scissors")
   elif (player == "paper"):
       print("You chose paper")

   #If there is a tie, print
   if player == ("paper"):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   if player == ("rock"):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   if player == ("scissors"):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   #If player beats bot
   if (player == "rock" ):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           print("Total shekels are", str(bet * 2 + bet_money))
           money = bet * 2 + bet_money

   if (player == "paper" ):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           print("Total shekels are", str(bet * 2 + bet_money))
           money = bet * 2 + bet_money

   if (player == "scissors" ):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           print("Total shekels are", str(bet * 2 + bet_money))
           money = bet * 2 + bet_money

       #If bot beats player
   if (player == "rock" ):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money - bet))
           money = money - bet

   if (player == "paper" ):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           print("Total sheckels are", str(money - bet))
           money = money - bet

   if (player == "scissors" ):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels ")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money - bet))
           money = money - bet

while True:
   bet()
```

Comment: I'm new here by the way!

Answer (score 0):

The function is using a local variable `money` when it should be using the global `money` variable.

Remove `money = money` and replace with `global money`

Answer (score 0):

There's still one small issue in the code, but I trust you can figure it out. It is only that you can answer a non-rock/paper/scissors answer and it will continue to play, but it's a simple fix. Message me again if you need help with that.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the casino")
money = 100

def bet():
   global money
   greeting = input("Would you like to bet? yes/no ")
   if greeting == ("yes"):
       pass
   elif greeting == ("no"):
       print("Then leave")
       exit()
   print("Total Money is: " + str(money))
   print("_____________________________________")
   player = input("Choose rock, paper, or scissors: ")
   bot = (random.randrange(1,4))
   rock = 1
   paper = 2
   scissors = 3

   if money <= 0:
       print("We don't let the poor bet")
       exit()
   else:
       pass
       #betting procedure
   print("You have " + str(money) + " shekels")
   print("How many shekels are you betting? ")

   betIsInt = str("False")

   
   bet = int(input("Max Bet: " + str(money) + "."))

   while(betIsInt == "False"):
      try:
         val = int(bet)
         while(int(bet) <= 0 or int(bet) > money):
          print("You can't bet that amount.")
          bet = input("How much do you want to bet? ")
         betIsInt = str("True")
      except ValueError:
         print("That is not a valid number.")
         bet = input("How much do you want to bet? ")
         
         
  
   while(int(bet) < 0 or int(bet) >= money):
      print("You can't bet that amount.")
      bet = input("How much do you want to bet? ")

   #if 0 < bet <= 100:
     #  bet_money = money - bet #total amount of money while betting
#   elif bet <= 0:
 #      print("That's not how it works, you've been kicked from the casino")
  #     exit()
  # else:
   #    print("That's not allowed, you've been kicked from the casino")
    #   exit()
     #  print("")

       #What Bot Picks,
   if (bot == 1):
       print("The computer chose rock")
   elif (bot == 2):
       print("The computer chose paper")
   elif (bot == 3):
       print("The computer chose scissors")

       #What Player Picks,
   if (player == "rock"):
       print("You chose rock")
   elif (player == "scissors"):
       print("You chose scissors")
   elif (player == "paper"):
       print("You chose paper")

   #If there is a tie, print
   if player == ("paper"):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   if player == ("rock"):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   if player == ("scissors"):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("")
           print("You Tied")
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
       else:
           print("")

   #If player beats bot
   if (player == "rock" ):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           money = money + bet
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
           

   if (player == "paper" ):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           money = money + bet
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))

   if (player == "scissors" ):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("The Player Wins")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           money = money + bet
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
          

       #If bot beats player
   if (player == "rock" ):
       if (bot == 2):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           money = money - bet
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
           

   if (player == "paper" ):
       if (bot == 3):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels")
           money = money - bet
           print("Total sheckels are", str(money))
           

   if (player == "scissors" ):
       if (bot == 1):
           print("The Computer Wins")
           print("The Player Lost:")
           print(str(bet) + " shekels ")
           money = money - bet
           print("Total shekels are", str(money))
           

while True:
   bet()
```